# Default field value for the duration of ALTER TABLE only

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server (at least 2017). I'm trying to add a new column to an existing table with rows in it. The column will not be nullable. I don't want the column to have a default value - I want the consumers to set it explicitly.

On the DDL level, is there an elegant way to add a column, setting its value for existing rows, but not for new ones?

Here are two inelegant ones that I can think of:

- add a column with a named default constraint, drop the default constraint immediately after
- add a column as nullable, set the value for all rows, then alter the datatype to make it non-nullable

From general principles, the latter is slightly worse than the former. Either way, I can (and have) implemented either of those approaches in SQL, no problem. But I wonder if there is a one liner...

This is not a "help me do this" question, this is a "can this be done better" question.

Comment: Your second proposal is the approach I'd normally use; you can't combine a DDL and DML operation.

Comment: In SQL Server, there is no direct one-liner to achieve the behavior you described, you need to add the field as nullable then
update existing records with the desired value
and alter the column to be non-nullable

Comment: That solution is likely not the better option, @AmiraBedhiafi . If standard/express it'll likely be as performance, but for Enterprise then it wouldn't be. Adding a column with a default value that is populated is a meta-data only change in Enterprise; forcing an `UPDATE` would not be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first option would be the better option here:

1. Create the column as not `NULL`able with a (named) `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT`.
2. `DROP` the `CONSTRAINT`.

As has been discussed in the comments there's no one-liner version, however, on Enterprise adding a column with a populated default value is a meta-data only change so the time it takes would be near instant. Dropping the `CONSTRAINT` afterwards doesn't change that either (it's still a meta-data only change).

The other option, to create the column and then `UPDATE` all the `NULL` values could be (very) costly , especially on a large table. Note that this method would be very similar to how the former option would work on Standard/Express, but that doesn't change my opinion on what is "better™"; you might as well write defensively should you end up using Enterprise in the future.

Comment: What's even more interesting is that it seems to keep track of the default constraint even after it was dropped https://dbfiddle.uk/lTITZqXK

Comment: Not that db<>fiddle uses Express though, @Charlieface , so it's not a meta-data only change then; the values are being written to the table instead.

Comment: @Charlieface - the metadata about the default value to use for rows where this column is not present is stored in `sys.system_internals_partition_columns` https://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/